# Given an integer, search an array to return the two items the integer falls between in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of game levels like this:

```
levels=[{points:0, level:One},{points:200, level:Two},{points:0, level:Three}..]
```

I have a points counter whose value changes as the game progresses i.e. counter=100. 
How do I search the array to find which items the counter value falls between and return the level values for both?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let levels=[{points:0, level:'One'},{points:200, level:'Two'},{points:400, level:'Three'}];
let counter = 210;
const filteredLevels = levels.filter(x=> counter >= x.points);
const maxPoint = Math.max.apply(Math, filteredLevels.map(p=> p.points));
var currentLevel = filteredLevels.find(y=> y.points === maxPoint); // result

console.log(currentLevel);
```

Gives the level in which the counter value falls

Comment: adjusting the current level definition to be greater than or equal vs. strict equal achieves the desired goal: var current_level = filteredLevels.find(y=> y.points >= maxPoint);

Answer (score 1):

You could use `arrays filter` method to search.

**Example**

```js
let levels = [{ points: 0, level: 'One' }, { points: 200, level: 'Two' }, { points: 300, level: 'Three' }];

//Example 1
let userPoints = 150;
let searchLevel = levels.filter( value =>  userPoints >= value.points);
console.log("Example 1: ", searchLevel);

//Example 2
userPoints = 250;
searchLevel = levels.filter( value =>  userPoints >= value.points);
console.log("Example 2: ", searchLevel);
```

Comment: What if the points fall between 0 and 200 i.e. 150? How would I get it to return the item for level: "One"?

Comment: I have change the logic from `value.points === userPoints` to `value.points >= userPoints`, Could you try this and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Example 2, where userPoints = 250 will return both level 'One' and 'Two'. Shouldn't it return the level with highest points i.e, 'Two'?

Comment: Example 2 will return only level 1 and level 2 and will not include leve3 as the user is not reached to level 3 yet.

Comment: Thanks Sohail - I was thinking of looping through the length of the results and returning the first entry's level value, but your response incorporates the desired result nicely